# Cassandra Compaction for Write and Read use cases

Tags: cassandra

We are planning to use Cassandra in one of our project, where we will have both heavy writes and moderate reads. On an average we will have writes around 250 tps and we are exposing REST API for downstream applications and expected reads are around 100 tps. Which compaction strategy best fit for our use case as we have both Write and read.  Any suggestion on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: do you plan to delete data from database? Do you plan to update data?

Comment: 90% of the transactions are update and deletion of data happens once in month based on certain criteria like products will be deleted when stock on hand becomes zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your workload, the default `SizeTieredCompactionStrategy` (STCS) would be the best choice, because:

- `LeveledCompactionStrategy` (LCS) is primarily designed for mostly read workloads with small number of updates/writes ([documentation](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/operating/compaction/index.html) says about updates as well, but my personal experience doesn't confirm that)
- `TimeWindowCompactionStrategy` (TWCS) is designed for append only workloads, where deletion happens via TTL

P.S. DataStax has created the [Unified Compaction Strategy (UCS)](https://github.com/datastax/cassandra/blob/ds-trunk/doc/unified_compaction.md), that is like a mix of STCS & LCS, but it's not clear if it will be included into Cassandra or not.